# Merge a list of pdfs and create new bookmarks (C#)

Tags: c#, itext

The project is in C# and use iTextSharp.

I have a dictionary with a title (string) and file content (byte array). I loop through this dictionary and merge all files together. What I need now is to add bookmarks to the start of the first page in each file, but I should not add any new pages or text to the final document. I have tried different solutions, but all seem to add a table of contents page, a new page before each page or some text at the start of the page.

None of the files have bookmarks originally.

I am looking for a bookmarks structure that looks something like this:

- File1
- File2
- SomeCategory

  - File3
  - File4

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

My function for merging the files looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Merge PDF files, and stamp certificates. This is a modified version of the example in the link below.
/// See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger for more information.            
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceFiles">Files to be merged</param>
/// <returns>Byte array with the combined files.</returns>
public static byte[] MergeFiles(Dictionary<string, byte[]> sourceFiles)
    {
        var document = new Document();
        var output = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            // Initialize pdf writer
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.PageEvent = new PdfPageEvents();

            // Open document to write
            document.Open();
            var content = writer.DirectContent;

            // Iterate through all pdf documents
            foreach (var sourceFile in sourceFiles)
            {
                // Create pdf reader
                var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile.Value);
                var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // Iterate through all pages
                for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <=
                                   numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
                {
                    // Determine page size for the current page
                    document.SetPageSize(
                       reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex));

                    // Create page
                    document.NewPage();

                    var importedPage =
                      writer.GetImportedPage(reader, currentPageIndex);

                    // Determine page orientation
                    var pageOrientation = reader.GetPageRotation(currentPageIndex);
                    if ((pageOrientation == 90) || (pageOrientation == 270))
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0,
                           reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(currentPageIndex).Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.AddTemplate(importedPage, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    }
                    // Add stamp to certificates
                    if (sourceFile.Key.IsValidDocumentReference())
                        AddStamp(content, document, sourceFile.Key, currentPageIndex, numberOfPages);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("An unexpected exception occured during the merging process", exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            document.Close();
        }
        return output.GetBuffer();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using `PdfWriter` instead of `PdfCopy`? Or have you just copied somebody's code without knowing that `PdfWriter` may be bad for your PDFs?

Comment: To be honest I do not know iTextSharp good enough, but I will look into pdfcopy.  Will that make my problem with the bookmarks easier?

Comment: "Easier" is a matter of opinion, but you'd benefit from already existing examples: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C07 http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=139 http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=140 http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=141

Comment: Thanks to your help Bruno, I was able to produce the code to solve my problem. I posted an answer below.

Comment: Great example! I'll need to bookmark this page for further reference.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie) who pointed me in the right direction, I was able to produce a solution to my problem.

This is my solution:

```
public static byte[] MergeFilesAndAddBookmarks(Dictionary<PrintDocument, byte[]> sourceFiles)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var document = new Document())
            {
                using (var copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    //Order the files by chapternumber
                    var files = sourceFiles.GroupBy(f => f.Key.ChapterNumber);

                    document.Open();

                    var outlines = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

                    var pageIndex = 1; 

                    foreach (var chapterGroup in files)
                    {
                        var map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        outlines.Add(map);
                        map.Add("Title", chapterGroup.First().Key.ChapterName);
                        var kids = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                        map.Add("Kids", kids);

                        foreach (var sourceFile in chapterGroup)
                        {
                            using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile.Value))
                            {
                                // add the pages
                                var n = reader.NumberOfPages;

                                for (var page = 0; page < n;)
                                {
                                    if (page == 0)
                                    {
                                        var kid = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                        kids.Add(kid);
                                        kid["Title"] = sourceFile.Key.Title;
                                        kid["Action"] = "GoTo";
                                        kid["Page"] = String.Format("{0} Fit", pageIndex);
                                    }
                                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                                }

                                pageIndex += n;
                                reader.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    copy.Outlines = outlines;
                    document.Close();
                    copy.Close();
                    ms.Close();
                }
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    } 
}

public class PrintDocument
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ChapterName { get; set; }
    public int ChapterNumber { get; set; }
}
```